# Can't access the sensors in Android

Tags: android, sensors

I am writing an compass application but can't access the sensors needed for some reason. 
I have implemented the `SensorEventListener` interface and register my sensors this way:

```
    sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    magnetometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
```

In my `onSensorChange()` method:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "onSensorChanged", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    t.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
    t.show();
    if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
        mGravity = event.values;
    }
    if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD){
        mGeomagnetic = event.values;
    }

    if(mGravity !=null && mGeomagnetic !=null){
        float [] R = new float[9];
        float [] I = new float [9];
        boolean success = sensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);
        if(success){
            float [] orientation = new float [3];
              sensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
            north = orientation[0];
        }
    }
}
```

The `Toast` message won't show on the screen and when I try to put the north value in a `TextView` the output is `0`. Would be great if someone could explain to me why I can't access the `onSensorChanged()` method. Permissions in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
sensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

Do not forget to unregister them.

More: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html

Comment: Because you don't register to this event. With the sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER); line you only access to the sensor. After it you have to register. This is simple event handling in java.

Comment: I know, but I thought I registered the sensor with getDefaultSensor()

Answer (score 0):

The gyroscope sensor Registration does not work in API 33.