# manifest.xml when using sensors

Tags: android

I am working in a project, it doesn't work and I suppose that the error is here:
should I write something in `manifest.xml` when I want to work with sensors : compass, gyroscope and accelerometer?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provide permissions in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

And also check below work:

```
sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
sensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

Do not forget to unregister them.

More: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html

Note: Android SDK folder also contains some helpful sensor sample applications

mark True or voteup if helpful...

Comment: you could just simply give a reference of this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970065/cant-access-the-sensors-in-android. It was not needed to copy and paste.

Answer (score 6):

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />
```

you have to declare this in `manifest.xml`

Comment: Sorry but it is not an obligation.

Comment: This is not required to use the sensor.  This is a Google Play filter that will restrict the app from devices that do not have an accelerometer.  This is documented at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html

Answer (score 0):

Manifest is the class where you can only write what application contains: application version, activitites, permissions etc. 
What type of data you want to entering. If you want to enter string. so place it in `strings.xml`.

Comment: should I write a permission for using Sensor there?