# How can I implement this class in my mainActivity

Tags: java, android, class

I found this class to use a compass but in the site I found it they don´t explain how to implement it, I mean, when I make the call to the class in the main activity and put the result only put the results once and do not keep refreshing the screen with the values... here is the class I Found:

```
public class Compass implements SensorEventListener{

private SensorManager sensorManager;
private Sensor gsensor;
private Sensor msensor;
private float[] mGravity = new float[3];
private float[] mGeomagnetic = new float[3];
private float azimuth = 0f;
private float correctAzimuth = 0;

public Compass(Context context){
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    gsensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    msensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    final float alpha = 0.97f;

    synchronized (this) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

            mGravity[0] = alpha * mGravity[0] + (1 - alpha)
                    * event.values[0];
            mGravity[1] = alpha * mGravity[1] + (1 - alpha)
                    * event.values[1];
            mGravity[2] = alpha * mGravity[2] + (1 - alpha)
                    * event.values[2];

            // mGravity = event.values;
            // Log.e(TAG, Float.toString(mGravity[0]));
        }

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
            // mGeomagnetic = event.values;

            mGeomagnetic[0] = alpha * mGeomagnetic[0] + (1 - alpha)
                    * event.values[0];
            mGeomagnetic[1] = alpha * mGeomagnetic[1] + (1 - alpha)
                    * event.values[1];
            mGeomagnetic[2] = alpha * mGeomagnetic[2] + (1 - alpha)
                    * event.values[2];
            // Log.e(TAG, Float.toString(event.values[0]));

        }

        float R[] = new float[9];
        float I[] = new float[9];
        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity,
                mGeomagnetic);
        if (success) {
            float orientation[] = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
            // Log.d(TAG, "azimuth (rad): " + azimuth);
            azimuth = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientation[0]); // orientation
            azimuth = (azimuth + 360) % 360;
            // Log.d(TAG, "azimuth (deg): " + azimuth);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
```

}

Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: Follow this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSensor/article.html -- you specifically forgot to register your class as a sensor listener. Ideally, you would do that in an activity or a service.

Comment: Hi @323go I try using the ORIENTATION_TYPE but is deprecated, and testing it sometimes give negative values... thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

I tried the code and it worked for me [after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970065/cant-access-the-sensors-in-android) I added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
```

in the manifest. And added

```
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, gsensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, msensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

to the Compass constructor.

To access the compass value you need a getter method for the azimuth variable in the Compass class.

Compass.onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Compass compass = new Compass(this);
}
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class Compass implements SensorEventListener{

    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor gsensor;
    private Sensor msensor;
    private float[] mGravity = new float[3];
    private float[] mGeomagnetic = new float[3];
    private float azimuth = 0f;
    private float correctAzimuth = 0;
    private String TAG = "Compass";

    public Compass(Context context)
    {
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        gsensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        msensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

        sensorManager.registerListener(this, gsensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, msensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) 
    {
        final float alpha = 0.97f;

        synchronized (this) 
        {
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) 
            {

                mGravity[0] = alpha * mGravity[0] + (1 - alpha)
                    * event.values[0];
                mGravity[1] = alpha * mGravity[1] + (1 - alpha)
                    * event.values[1];
                mGravity[2] = alpha * mGravity[2] + (1 - alpha)
                    * event.values[2];

                // mGravity = event.values;
                // Log.e(TAG, Float.toString(mGravity[0]));
            }

            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) 
            {
                // mGeomagnetic = event.values;

                mGeomagnetic[0] = alpha * mGeomagnetic[0] + (1 - alpha)
                    * event.values[0];
                mGeomagnetic[1] = alpha * mGeomagnetic[1] + (1 - alpha)
                    * event.values[1];
                mGeomagnetic[2] = alpha * mGeomagnetic[2] + (1 - alpha)
                    * event.values[2];
                // Log.e(TAG, Float.toString(event.values[0]));

            }

            float R[] = new float[9];
            float I[] = new float[9];
            boolean success = SensorManager.
                    getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);
            if (success) 
            {
                float orientation[] = new float[3];
                SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
                // Log.d(TAG, "azimuth (rad): " + azimuth);
                azimuth = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientation[0]); // orientation
                azimuth = (azimuth + 360) % 360;

                Log.d(TAG, "azimuth (deg): " + azimuth);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Yannic Welle can you post me the code you use in the mainActivity please? I add the permission but still not working... thanks for the reply! :)

Comment: I got the code at work, remind me if I did not post it till tomorrow afternoon.

Comment: For the meantime: All I did was useing the constructor to build a Compass object in MainActivity.onCreate(). I tried it with a phone watch and a smartphone. The Compass.onSensorChange() is called on the smartphone only - are you sure your device got the right hardware?

Comment: yea @yannic, i had a samsung p6800 7.7" it says it had all of the sensors

Comment: ok added the Compass.java and the MainActivity.onCreate. This should let you see the current azimuth value in your LogCat window.

Comment: Hi @Yannic, yea it works, but the things is that I cannot make it to send the values to my Main_activity each time the onSensorChange...

Comment: You could add a `public static void updateAzimuth(float newAzimuth) {/* update all you need here */}` to your MainActivity.